# Which raid array will be best practices with seven 1.2 tb hdd system

Tags: raid, performance, hardware-raid, raid5, raid6

I have a server which have seven 1.2 tb hard disks. I have to create raid array but i don't decide which raid i use?

First of all, first and most important matter is security. At any cost i must not to lose data. So, i think raid 6 and one hot sphere will be ok. but i saw that article http://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-6-stops-working-in-2019/ and i surprised. Maybe even raid6 will not be protect such a large capacity disks?

What will be best practise to this situation?

Thanks and regards...

Comment: BACKUP your data. RAID is not meant for disaster recovery, it is made for high availability. BACKUP YOUR DATA!

Comment: Sure I will. Just like you said, i want to high availability too. And performance sure. But ı confused raid 5 about security and raid 6 about performance.

Comment: Raid 6 is safer. Raid 6 is slower. NONE has good performance.

Comment: Did you even bother looking up some reference ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels))about RAID levels and what robustness they provide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - backups. RAID is not a replacement.

Second - I would not go with hardware raid any more. On Linux you have ZFS, on Windows you have storage spaces. Both can provide a Raid 6 level security, but both can handle rebuilds a lot more gracefully.

And both are cheaper - the cost of a decent hardware raid controller is not trivial. It **was** worth it in the past, it still is possibly worth it for some things, but I would strongly push towards a software solution these days.

> At any cost i must not to lose data.

ONLY backupS protect. Note the S - at least 2, better 3. One may be local, but the other 2 must NOT be local (any cost includes flooding and fire). That is where a tape library comes in handy, or cloud backups (to 2 providers).

Note that most data loss also has to take into account user error. Happens. Raid does not protect from those.

Comment: Curse you, fast typist man!  +1 for saying *almost exactly* what I was half way through saying.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have no chance buy a storage, i have to trust raid array. I just not know which i choose. Raid5 or raid6?

Comment: Well, what about just deleting the data? Because this WILL HAPPEN anyway. You contradict yourself. And Raid 6 is NOT safe - nothing is. If you HAVE to RELY on Raid 6 and CAN NOT LOOSE DATA - just delete the data, it will happen anyway. And do not come to a place where professionals talk. Remember how you lied? Let me quote: "At any cost i must not to lose data". At any cost.